# Jetpack Compose: The layout inspector is not showing the menu for recomposition counts

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition, layout-inspector

Android Studio Bumblebee Patch 3

From this page, it says that I can see recomposition counts:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#recomposition-counts

It does not show the menu option to me. Only the device name and "Stop inspector"

Comment: Have you tried the current stable version (Chipmunk)?

Comment: Same thing. I think I am missing something to enable that menu.

Comment: Do you have the right `ui-tooling` and `ui-tooling-preview` dependencies mentioned at the top of https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling?

Comment: Yes, compose version 1.1.1

Answer (score 21):

### You just need to enable this option in View Options

[image]

Answer (score 14):

This is only available in Electric Eel at the moment:

"For even more cutting edge features, you can take a sneak peek at the Android Studio Electric Eel release in the Canary channel [...] These features will be promoted to more stable channels once we have your feedback and make improvements, so please try them out." [Source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/whats-new-in-android-studio.html)

Comment: They mention EE for Live Edit in the Tooling page, but they don't for Layout Inspector. I will wait for a stable release, I am just beginning my project. Thanks and enjoy your 50 points :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks :-), I'm using the recomposition counts on EE and it works nicely. I have actually sorted out an infinite recomposition loop that I was not aware of... I recommend it!

Comment: @CodePoet may i know which version of EE you are using? i still can't make it appear

Comment: @dwqdq13213 I am currently on Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 5

Comment: @CodePoet i successfully make it show up when i open google's sample, but when it comes to my working project that contains more than 30 sub-modules, it doesn't work. not sure what happens 

Comment: @dwqdq13213 Sorry, I don't know. Maybe it's a bug. But I would suggest you open your own question in case someone can help.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue, and found the official site has noted that, after upgrade compose version and use Android Studio Preview version, it works for me:

> To get started, make sure your app is using Compose 1.2.0-alpha03 or higher. Then deploy your app as you normally would.